# Enable squid proxy blocking https

Tags: squid

I'm trying to block some sites like gmail and outlook from my squid proxy server.
My squid.conf is:

```
acl blacklist dstdomain "/etc/squid/blacklist.acl"
http_access deny blacklist
```

And blacklist.acl is:

```
.atlassian.net
.accounts.google.com
.mail.google.com
.gmail.com
.gmail.google.com
```

This only seems to work for sites using http (ie. they successfully get blocked)
https sites still are able to get through ?

I'm running squid 4.10 on Ubuntu-20.04

Does anyone know how to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is probably because you haven't enabled SSL bumping, i.e. your `http_port` directive is set to the default `http_port 3128`.

I've written about both Squid's SSL setup and blocking websites

- [configure squid with ICAP & SSL](https://www.egirna.com/post/configure-squid-4-17-with-icap-ssl)
- [block and allow websites with squid](https://www.egirna.com/post/allowing-blocking-websites-using-squid)

Answer (score 0):

When the site is encrypted squid can validate only the Domain but not the entire URL path or keywords in the URL. To block https sites using `urlpath_regex` we need to setup Squid proxy using `SSLbump`. It is tricky and a long process , need to carefully configure the SSL bump settings by generating certificates.. but it is possible . I have succeeded in blocking the websites using `urlpathregex` over https sites...

For more detailed explanation:

`Squid.conf` file should have the below to achieve block websites using Keywords or Path ie..`urlpath_regex`

```
http_port 3128 ssl-bump cert=/usr/local/squid/certificate.pem generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB

acl BlockedKeywords url_regex -i "/etc/squid/.."

acl BlockedURLpath urlpath_regex -i "/etc/squid/..."

acl BlockedFIles urlpath_regex -i "/etc/squid3/...."

http_access deny BlockedKeywords

http_access deny BlockedFIles

http_access deny BlockedURLpath
```